# Is any method can get current file path?

Tags: r

Sorry for bothering with trivial things. For example abc.R is run under c:\temp. How to get the path inside the code? I am trying to avoid writing a fixed path, which can make it more dynamic. Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for is usually referred to as the "working directory."  I don't use r, but this might help: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html

Comment: Can you give a bit more info about how you'll use it?  You can use `getwd` but sometimes you specify a path as in `./dir`.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to find the current working directory, try having a look at `?getwd`.